# Running Remote UI Tests

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, automated-tests, integration-testing

What options do we have in order to run UI tests on WPF-app remotely? I tried several times to set up TestController\TestAgent, but they are so buggy, I haven't finished troubleshooting problems I faced with. Do we have other options?

Comment: Is it just for web apps? I have coded UI tests for a WPF app.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work for WPF-desktop apps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Test Stack framework (formerly known as White)

http://www.teststack.net/v1.0/blog/new-docs-site/